# Getting local html inside another local html with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have got one html file in my PC that I use for work and I want to load another local html file to it, I want it to be loaded inside one div.  `<div id="loadHere"></div>`

I used this jquery function but it's not working `$("#loadHere").load("001.html")`

When I do that I get this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/**censored**/Desktop/**censored**/html/00.html. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.
jquery.min.js:132 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'responseText' of null
```

I understand that this is done because of security and there is propably no safe way to turn it off (for example for one folder).

So I was thinking about alternative solution, what if I had some drag&drop space on my main html file, where I could just drag and drop local html file that I want to load inside `<div id="loadHere"></div>`.

Is that possible? If yes, where should I start? Is there some framework for that? My idea was that after I would drop that file on drag&drop area it would get saved in some variable and with that variable it would be really easy to load it inside that div.

Thanks and have a nice day.

Comment: you should use a simple light webserver

Comment: I can't do that in work, that's why I'm seeking for a workaround.

Comment: you can turn it off in chrome `--disable-web-security`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At chromium / chrome browsers , try adjusting launcher to

chromium

```
/path/to/chromium-browser --allow-access-from-files
```

chrome

```
/path/to/google-chrome --allow-file-access-from-files
```

See

[How do I make the Google Chrome flag “--allow-file-access-from-files” permanent?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/160245/how-do-i-make-the-google-chrome-flag-allow-file-access-from-files-permanent)

[List of Chromium Command Line Switches](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/)

Answer (score 2):

Best and easiest way to use iframe:

```
<iframe id="loadHere" src="001.html"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest workaround that works with any browser - just load it in an iframe instead of a div:

`<iframe id="loadHere" src="loadHere.html"></iframe>`

OR set src with JS:

`document.getElementById('loadHere').src = "something.html";`

Comment: Well, that is nice solution but it doesn't take CSS from main html file.

Comment: True. An aditional workaround would be to include the css in any html file you load.